# ServiceStack Rockstars - why does it not redirect to folder/ with IIS Express?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying out ServiceStack, and have cloned the RazorRockstars sample from Github.

If I open in Visual Studio 2012 and start `RazorRockstars.WebHost` project, it all runs fine in VS development server.

If I then change the project to use IIS Express 8, the URLs in the dead/alive menus no longer work correctly.

It turns out that the link in the menu points to directory name without a slash: `http://localhost:2000/stars/alive/vedder`, and when executed, the server will send back a `302` and redirect to `http://localhost:2000/stars/alive/vedder/` (note the trailing slash), and after that all is well.

In IIS Express however, this redirect doesn't happen, and the url in the browser remains without a slash, which in turn breaks the page.

The interesting part, however, is that the `default.cshtml` page will execute from the directory, but the included partial `content.md` will not. It looks as if SS is aware this was a folder and will look correctly for `default.cshtml`, but then somehow fails to look for `content.md` partial.

Is this a bug with SS implementation or expected behavior? Presumably it would make sense for ServiceStack itself to return a `301` in this situation.

Comment: Looks like IIS automatically does the redirect, whist IIS Express does not.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.

I had to download the URL rewrite module for IIS. And create a rewrite rule in the web.config file in the RazorRockstars.WebHost project.

See this link for more detailed explaination. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-urls-of-your-asp-net-web-site-with-iis-7-url-rewrite-module